# Proccessing 2 million records with perl

Tags: perl

I have 2 million records on the database is it possible to bring them all and store them on perl hash reference without any problem of reaching out of memory ?

Comment: Is this a one time ordeal, or something for a regular basis?

Comment: It sounds to me as though you are asking The Wrong Question. What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: As a tiny datapoint perl -E "for (1..2_000_000) {$f{$_} = $_}; say qq{exists}; sleep 20" consumes about 270M on a 32 bit Strawberry perl. Your best bet here, is just to try it quickly on test data and see what happens.

Comment: @Alex, good for you, always best to check!

Comment: I suppose it really depends on the size of the record.

Comment: @davorg, I'm sure thats true, but at 270M you are playing in a reasonable ballpark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is your reason to read them all into memory? Speed or ease of coding (i.e. treat the whole thing as a hashref).

If its the former, then sure, I think, you just need a ton of ram.

If its the latter, then there are interesting options. For example there are `tie`d interfaces for databases that look like Perl native hashes but in reality query and return data as needed. A quick search of CPAN shows [`Tie::DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aDBI), [`Tie::Hash::DBD`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aHash%3a%3aDBD) and several tied interfaces for specific databases, flat-file DBs, and CSV files, including mine [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV).

Comment: Is it possible with Tie::DBI to implement hash of hashs i.e to achive somthing like this : $hash->{key1}->{key2}->{value}  ?

Comment: Some of the examples look like they might have some ability to do that. If thats not what you want, you can look at what I did to implement 2D tied arrays in my `Tie::Array::CSV` code.

Comment: Could you provide an example if possible ?

Comment: nope, I don't have your data, and I don't completely know how you might map a table to such a structure. Sorry. Read the examples, if they don't help you will have to find someone who uses it. I just am aware that it exists.

Answer (score 3):

On the one hand, processing two million elements in a hash isn't unheard of.  However, we don't know how big your records are.  At any rate, it sounds like an XY problem.  It may not be the best solution for the problem you're facing.

Why not use [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass) so that your tables can be treated like Perl classes (which are themselves glorified data-structures)?  There's a ton of documentation at [DBIx::Class::Manual::DocMap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aDocMap).  This is really what DBIx::Class is all about; letting you abstract away the SQL details of the database and treat it like a series of classes.

Comment: I meant to make that comment, and then forgot. Thanks. Probably better to come from someone who uses it. Thankfully I don't need to get into databases all that often.

Answer (score 2):

That completely depends on how much data your records have. Perl hashes and arrays take up more memory than you'd think although it's not crazy. But again, it totally depends on what your data looks like and how much RAM you have. Perl won't have any problems with it if you have the RAM.